# Version Control And Strapi

Tags: git, version-control, strapi

I am confused about version control in Strapi. Do I put the entire JavaScript codebase in version control? Are there any directories I need to exclude because they are not needed or are a security vulnerability? When I deploy an app, what else do I need besides the files in version control and the '.env' to deploy the app; is there information in the database that is essential to the app that also needs to be migrated? Do I need to put the database in version control?

Comment: Why not put under version control what you write as source code and omit everything from version control that is automatically generated from the sources, as usual?

Comment: because when you modify Strapi through the front end, it modifies the javascript, not just the database. so using the app requires version control afaik.

Comment: that is part of the reason I am asking the question. What can I put in version control and what is unnecessary?